# Git: delete all remote branches with a certain pattern

Tags: git, grep, xargs

I would like to execute a single command which deletes branches on the *remote* that follow a certain pattern.

Example use case:
**Delete all branches on `origin` that begin with `v1/`.**

If possible, it would be nice to enhance this command with a safety check: only delete branches which have been merged into `master`.

Answer (score 5):

To list such branches :

```
git for-each-ref --merged master \
   --format="%(refname:short)" refs/remotes/origin/v1

# if you want only the `v1/xxx` part without the leading `origin/` :
git for-each-ref --merged master \
    --format="%(refname:lstrip=3)" refs/remotes/origin/v1
```

You can then feed its output to `git push origin -d` :

```
git for-each-ref --merged master \
    --format="%(refname:lstrip=3)" refs/remotes/origin/v1 |\
    xargs git push origin -d
```

---

*note* : the syntax to use [`git for-each-ref`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref) is a bit more intricate than the one for `git branch`, but its output is stable, highly configurable with the [`--format`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt---formatltformatgt) option and suitable for scripting. `git branch` is intended for human reading and has several formatting options which make for annoying bugs in scripts (leading `*` on the active branch, non configurable specific spacing ...)

for reference, the equivalent command using `git branch` would be :

```
git branch --merged master -r --list origin/v1
```

Answer (score 1):

## List all branches on `origin` that begin with `v1/`

```sh
git branch --remotes --merged master --list 'origin/v1/*' --format '%(refname:lstrip=3)'
```

## Remove all branches on `origin` that begin with `v1/`

```sh
git branch --remotes --merged master --list 'origin/v1/*' --format '%(refname:lstrip=3)' |
  xargs git push --delete origin
```